# How to show a camera preview with the new android.hardware.camera2 API?

Tags: android, scaling, android-camera2

I want to replace the deprecated camera api with the android.hardware.camera2 api. The example project on github shows the camera picture but creates a black stripe on the edge of the screen if the resolution of the Device doesn't match perfect the camera scaling options. I've tried it on an Emulator (Android 26-29, Nexus 2). Same result as on the Samsung devices SM-T395 and SM-T585. On FullHD it is quite strange.

Increasing the `MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT` and `MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH` doesn't help.
I think I need to take

Here some example picture of the emulator:

[image: Custom resolution with quite a good fit] [image: FullHD sample]

How to show a preview of the camera in a custom sized preview?

Comment: You should use [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax), for better compatibility on lower SDK devices

Comment: I've seen it but as the documentation said: It is in alpha state. I need this for production. When it is finalized it might be a good option

Comment: You can use this sdk https://github.com/OmarAflak/Android-Camera2-Library for all basic feature of camera2

Comment: This library is not actively maintained. I can't use those kind of software in production. A fast look at the samples and I saw some errors in the code. This don't appears like well created code. Have you used it before?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is quite device dependent. Each vendor sets and list of supported resolutions for their camera. Moreover it can differ for the preview and actual image capturing(rarely but still). You cannot go beyond this list if you do not want to warp and distort your images and preview.

Not everything is so depressing though. Usually among this list there are several supported resolutions that have aspect ratio the same as the screen of the phone(or at least ones that will add black space on top or bottom of the image, but not on the side)

So what I would recommend is to find the aspect ratio of your screen(TextureView/SurfaceView). Calculate all the supported preview aspect ratios for your camera. Compare those ratios and choose the one with the same ratio as your screen(TextureView/SurfaceView) but with the largest resolution. The similar you may achieve for the resolutions that may show black space on top or bottom but not on the side.

Here is an example code that does similar thing but in a bit different manner.

```
//Create TextureView & TextureView surfaceTextureListener
private TextureView mTextureView;
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener =
            new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                    setupCamera(width, height);
                }
                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                    return false;
                }
                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                }
            };
//Implement Activity onResume
@Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       if(mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
       } else {
           mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
       }
   }
//Get surface preview sizes & camera Id
private void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
       CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
       try {
           for(String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
               CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
               if(cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                       CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT){
                   continue;
               }
               StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
               mPreviewSize = getPreferredPreviewSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), width, height);
               mCameraId = cameraId;
               return;
           }
       } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   private Size getPreferredPreviewSize(Size[] mapSizes, int width, int height) {
       List<Size> collectorSizes = new ArrayList<>();
       for(Size option : mapSizes) {
           if(width > height) {
               if(option.getWidth() > width &&
                       option.getHeight() > height) {
                   collectorSizes.add(option);
               }
           } else {
               if(option.getWidth() > height &&
                       option.getHeight() > width) {
                   collectorSizes.add(option);
               }
           }
       }
       if(collectorSizes.size() > 0) {
           return Collections.min(collectorSizes, new Comparator<Size>() {
               @Override
               public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
                   return Long.signum(lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() - rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
               }
           });
       }
       return mapSizes[0];
   }
```

Taken from [here](https://www.nigeapptuts.com/camera2-api-surface-preview-sizes/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: doesn't solved my problem. I have still black stripes. No of the provided resolutions matches the required. Is there a way use a bigger resulution and show only part of it?

Comment: Well you can do such things via manipulating with preview frames directly. But it is a matter of whole other kind, and there are plenty of info online regarding this since it is a way they implement masks.

Answer (score 0):

Just clone below link GitHub code and rut it.

https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2VideoJava/

here is full explanation of camera 2 api.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera

Comment: I think it's not clear. The screenshots are from the sample app

Comment: I run the Camera2BasicJava. I'll edit my question when I have access to a computer this evening. 
Then I try the other example